# Which groups of people read the 10 Commandments using the "lower" trope?

Tags: torah-reading, trop-cantillation, aseres-hadibros

See [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67645/5275) for a brief description of "upper" vs. "lower" trope for the 10 Commandments.

Most Nusach Ashkenaz shuls that I have attended use the upper trope while reading the 10 Commandments. The 10 Commandments are read 3 times during the year:

- Shabbat weekly reading of Yitro
- 1st day of Shavu'ot
- Shabbat weekly reading of Va'etchanan

On all 3 occasions, I have heard it read using the "upper" trope.

Are there any communities / nuscha'ot exiting today, that read it using the "lower" trope version, as part of one of the above readings? Do they do this throughout the year or switch it for one of the 3 above occasions? If you know why they do this, (i.e. - lower always or switching), please add this info to your answer.

Are there any halachic opinions that state a preference and / or time to use one version vs. the other?

Comment: Do you mean as part of the public reading of the Torah?

Comment: In general Ashkenazim use Taam Elyon only on Shavuot, Sefardim use it whenever reading the Torah, and Teimanim use it even in private. In the last century or so traditions have become sorta mixed, unfortunately.

Comment: What I have seen: in America they use the taami elyon always, in Israel on Shevous but not for the weekly readings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would seem that original Minhag Ashkenaz was to use *ta'am elyon* only on Shavu'ot, but on *shabbat parashat yitro* and *shabbat parashat va'etchanan* to use *ta'am tachton*. This can be seen in the commentary of [Hizkuni to Shemot 20:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.20.14?lang=bi), and is also the practice prescribed by [Masat Binyamin](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7), quoted in [Magen Avraham 494:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.494?lang=bi).

Magen Avraham  also notes the Sephardic practice, as described by [R. Ya'akov ibn Haviv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ibn_Habib) and [R. Menahem de Lonzano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Lonzano), to always use *ta'am elyon* in public.

Interestingly, there seem to be many relatively old examples of Ashkenazim following the Sephardic custom. For example, R. Yoseph b. Moshe writes in [Leket Yosher](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49438&st=%25u05E0%25u05D2%25u05D9%25u05E0%25u05D5%25u05EA&pgnum=29) that his teacher [R. Yisrael Isserlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Isserlein) would always use *ta'am elyon* for public reading, and would only use *ta'am tachton* during private study. Similary, [R. Moshe Sofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sofer) in [Responsa Hatam Sofer Yoreh De'ah 260](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.260.5?lang=bi) implies that *ta'am tachton* is only used for private study, with *ta'am elyon* used for all public reading.

As far as why one would differentiate between the reading on Shavu'ot and regular *shabbatot*, R. Yoseph Dov Soloveitchik, quoted in [Reshimot Shi'urim Berachot 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Reshimot_Shiurim_on_Berakhot.12a.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), suggests that the use of *ta'am elyon* is to, in a sense, recreate the experience of the Giving of the Torah at Mt Sinai, whereby we read each individual commandment as its own verse. The differing customs then reflect a disagreement as to whether this 'recreation' is only done on Shavu'ot, the anniversary of the Giving of the Torah, or instead whenever the Decalogue is read publically.

Finally, R. Soloveitchik notes that his grandfather, R. Haim Soloveitchik, only ever used *ta'am tachton*, even on Shavu'ot, as he did not want to break up verses in a different way to (what he believed was) the authentic tradition.