# Taamei Elyon for the Aseret Hadibrot

Tags: minhag, torah-reading

How did the custom of leining the aseret hadibrot with a special tune develop?

Comment: What is the source for any taamim? Please flesh out your question so we get you the info you actually want

Comment: What's the special tune? If you mean taam elyon, why is that a special tune?

Comment: Is your question covered by [this similar question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/origin-need-and-purpose-of-upper-trope-for-reading-10-commandments)?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know what's unclear about this, assuming (which is a big assumption) that the average reader knows that the Decalogue is read with a different tune than the standard _taam tachton_ written in the _chumashim_. That said, it does seem to be a duplicate of the question linked to by Rish.